# Why is Google Analytics not showing data but shows property hits?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I recently setup Google Analytics on my website, hosted on a VPS I manage. This is a plain HTML webpage, not a CMS like Wordpress (not sure if that matters?) I copied and pasted the following right above the `</head>` tag.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-########-#', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

When I login to Google Analytics I see values in Property Hit Volume:

[image]

Despite these hits, there is no data in Audience Overview or anywhere else in the portal. I created a View with default settings from Property Settings, so there are no filters in place.

[image]

Am I missing anything in my script or settings that I should have enabled?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when you created the view. Views will only accumulate data from when they are created. So that might be a reason as to why you are not seeing any traffic on the reporting side.

The easiest way to test if the tracking code implementation works is to go to the website and then check the real-time view in Google Analytics. If you cannot see yourself there, you have issues with the tracking code.

Comment: View was created a few days ago. I don't see any data in the real-time view either. I downloaded Tag Assistant plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) to make sure the site was posting to Goolge Analytics and it is.

Comment: interesting. Are you sure the UA code you are using is the right one from your property? If analytics are getting send fine but views don't show anything, you might be sending pageviews to the wrong property. Also check the webaite URL in your GA view settings and the hostname of your vps. GA will filter out hits that aren't coming from the given hostname. That is the same reason as to why file://...html wont work but rather you having to serve it through a webserver

Comment: The property ID is exactly the same in Property Settings and in website code. The hostname of VPS is an interesting detail, what all do I need to check for that? Using Fiddler I was able to catch the message sent and it looks like the Referer: http://website.com is correct.

Comment: if you ssh into the VPS ( assuming linux ) you can run 'hostname' in the bash shell to check what the OS is using. Also check the config of the webserver (the vhost entry in /etc/apache2/sites-available in the case of apache. It has the 'ServerName' property). Also check the protocol set up in the view setting. http vs https has to match what you're running. Also check for javascript errors in the console. Last but not least, certain adblockers prevent GA from firing.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: 1. set hostname to same as domain name
2. made sure ServerName in apache2 matches hostname
3. created a view for each protocol, just in case
4. no js errors
5. no adblockers

still no luck :(

Comment: Fascinating. Mind sharing the URL to the site?

Comment: I've made a tag-assistant recording and it validated that the pageview hit was indeed fired to GA. There is no logical reason as to why you wouldn't see it in GA.
Btw, there was a JS error on at the bottom of the page, your document.getElementById is finding null. A broken eventListener could mess with GA but shouldn't.

Comment: noooooo VERB! :) You were my last hope! Thanks for all the help anyways!

Comment: VERB, thank you for your help. I believe the process started working somewhere during your answer chain. However, the view did not show data till I deleted the existing property and recreated a new one with www.

Comment: If it is the www. you might want to also look at your DNS options to set an A record for the IP of your server and then just point www. to that A record. That'll avoid such issues.

Answer (score 3):

I usually check the following:

**-- please leave a comment if you want to add s.th. to the list**

- UA-########-# is set correctly
- JavaScript is enabled
- no adBlockers enabled
- tried a different browser (just for test purposes)
- no errors in console (browser console, developer tools)
- created some hits (reload the page a few times)
- waited a few hours (and then create a few more hits)
- hostname has to be the same as URL

If nothing else helps, create a minimal page test case:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-########-#', 'auto');
    console.log('-- ga send before --');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    console.log('-- ga send --');
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>analytics test</h1>
  <p>check console output</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This answer helps, thank you! One thing to add in your list is "hostname has to be the same as URL"

Comment: Thanks @Tigerjz32 – added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check, which I've just come across, is that you don't have any forgotten filters which might be stopping traffic from showing up. In our case, someone had added an exclude filter months earlier that stripped all traffic to the *www* subdomain (possibly an effort to stop spam). This was working OK until we moved web hosts and all traffic started being redirected to a new *www* subdomain, but obviously we had forgotten to turn off the filter.

In our case, the Google Tag Assistant was all good, we could see the hits in the Admin console, but there was just no data in the views. As soon as we removed the filter, the hits started reflecting immediately in our views.

To get to the Filters,

1. Log into your Analytics account
2. Click on the *Admin* menu item
3. Click the *All Filters* submenu
4. Check your list of filters for the property, particularly those with an *Exclude* type and delete any that might be stopping traffic in your views.